# install() directly to /etc/udev/rules.d

Tags: bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a policy on this? It's a problem if the same package in different rosdistros install the same file.

Options:

- Install the file to a name like `xyz-hydro.rules`, so that there's no conflict.
- Create a non-distro package which installs the rules, that the distro packages can depend on.
- Don't install them; make it a manual step for the user to copy them from /opt/ros/hydro/share into the system location.
- Install to share, but provide a postinst script to copy/link to udev/rules.d

What's the process to add a non-distro package to `packages.ros.org`? Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133966/install()-directly-to-/etc/udev/rules.d/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-27**:
I think the non-distro package is the cleanest, but I'm not sure how easy it will be to get it accepted into the ROS deb repository.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-24**:
Not a policy afaik, but for "least system-wide infection" with "most ease of use", I like the way that kobuki_ftdi installs rules. Basically `rosrun kobuki_ftdi create_udev_rules` will use the correct copy command + sudo and do that.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-03-26**:
@dornhege: That's what we've historically done (with Clearpath platforms). We're trying to get away from needing that manual rosrun install step, though.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-28**:
In that case I'd also go for a non-distro package. Maybe ask at ros-release for something official?

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-06-03**:
Is there something official? Isn't creating another package for just one rule file a bit of an overkill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of bloom 0.5.13, you can supply files in a "debian" folder in your package, and the various debhelpers, including `dh_installudev` will pick them up. You can see this in action in pointgrey_camera_driver:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/pointgrey_camera_driver/tree/master/pointgrey_camera_driver/debian

The appropriate rule gets installed by the debian package, using the proper udev machinery, but there's no pollution of the regular `catkin install` procedure.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4